# Install Haskell packages using cabal without internet connection

Tags: haskell, offline, cabal, cabal-install

I have a machine that doesn't have internet access at all.
I installed the Haskell Platform on it using the installer which I got from another machine through a pendrive.

Now I want to install the package `repa` on my home machine which has no internet access. How should I do that?

My home machine is running Linux (Debian) and my office machine is Windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a machine you can access the internet you can either:

- Run `cabal get pkg-name` where `pkg-name` is the package you want.
- Go to the package's page on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/) and on the Downloads section there's a `.tar.gz` file you can download.

After you get it, transfer it to your other machine, extract it anywhere you'd like (a sandbox if you want it just in a sandbox). Then from that directory (where there's a `.cabal` file) run `cabal install`.

Comment: Is there a quick way to find the dependencies of the package and download those as well, or must this be done manually?

Comment: @DNA Not that I know of, but writing a tool for that should be very easy since Cabal is also on Hackage. You could get the package (however you want; e.g. you could call `cabal get` using `System.Process`), then simply use the Cabal package to parse the cabal file, and then just recursively do the same for package dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Package managers, such as [cabal](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/), work internally to get a package from a remote repository. I doubt there exist an easy workaround to make cabal install a package in offline mode.

Probably the easiest way is to find a compressed version of package, find a way to get them on the offline computer (local sharing, thumb drive, etc.) and [install a package manually](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/How_to_install_a_Cabal_package).

Comment: There is no terrible difficulty in getting Cabal to install a package offline as long as the package and all its dependencies are locally available.